# I am wondering why my useEffect data is empty on first render when I populate it on first render using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, conditional-operator

I am creating an app using the REST countries API and I make an API call on the first render using useEffect hook and populate my useState array with the data that I need. When I try accessing this data in the return statement for the component it reads undefined. I even tried adding a ternary operator to first check if the data is empty and if not output it but it still reads undefined but If I comment out the code and refresh the page the data become populated and can then uncomment the code for it to show and if I were to refresh the page again the data reads as undefined. I am extremely confused as to why this is happening so any help is much appreciated.

My js file:

```
const CountryInfo = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([{}])
    let countryName = window.location.pathname;

    countryName = countryName.replace('/', '');
    countryName = countryName.split('%20');
    countryName = countryName.join(' ');
    console.log(countryName)

    useEffect(() => {
       axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${countryName}`).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        setData([{
            name: countryName,
            image: response.data[0].flags.png,
            nativeName: response.data[0].name.nativeName.nld,
            population: response.data[0].population,
            region: response.data[0].region,
            subRegion: response.data[0].subregion,
            capital: response.data[0].capital[0],
            borderCountries: response.data[0].borders,
            topLevelDomain: response.data[0].tld[0],
            currencies: response.data[0].currencies,
            languages: response.data[0].languages,
        }])
       }) 
    },[])

    console.log(data)

    return(
        <div className='country-info-content'>
            <Link to='/' className='info-button'>
                <button className='button-info'>BACK</button>
            </Link>
            <div className='data-info'>
                <img src={data[0].image} className='flag-img'/>
                <div className='country-name'>
                    <span className='name'>{data[0].name}</span>
                    <div className='info-description'>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <span>Native Name:</span> {data[0].nativeName.common}
                            </div>
                        {/* {data?
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                <span className='title'>Native Name:</span> {data.nativeName.common}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span className='title'>Population:</span> {data.population.toLocaleString(undefined)}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span className='title'>Region:</span> {data.region}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span className='title'>Sub Region:</span> {data.subRegion}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span className='title'>Capital:</span> {data.capital}
                                </div> 
                            </div>:null} */}
                            {/* {data ?
                                <div>
                                    <span>Native Name: </span>{data[0].nativeName.common}
                                </div>: null
                            } */}
                        </div>
                        <div className='right-info'>
                            <div>
                                <span className='title'>Top Level Domain:</span> {data.topLevelDomain}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span className='title'>Currency:</span> {data.topLevelDomain}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span className='title'>Languages:</span> {data.topLevelDomain}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CountryInfo;
```

[image: Output to the web]

Answer (score 2):

useEffect will trigger **AFTER** your page is rendered for the first time, that's why data is undefined the first time component renders.

You'll need to handle it and the ternary operator is a common practice:

```
return data ? <div>...</div> : null;
```

or

```
return data ? <div>...</div> : <div>Loading...</div>;
```

**UPDATE:**
The error message is triggered by reading `common` property of undefined. The only place where you do this is

```
data[0].nativeName.common
```

This means that `data[0]` exists, but `nativeName` is undefined. `nativeName` stores the value of `response.data[0].name.nativeName.nld,`.
You should double check if data returned from the API has expected format and `response.data[0].name.nativeName.nld` is set.

**UPDATE2**:
Like Zeno noticed in the comment, default value for `data` is `[{}]`, and that will always evaluate to `true` in ternary operator.

Why not make the default `undefined` until data is fetched?

Also make sure you refer to the results as `data[0]` as this is where you store the response. Or simplify your code a bit by doing:

```
setData({
            name: countryName,
            image: response.data[0].flags.png,
            nativeName: response.data[0].name.nativeName.nld,
            population: response.data[0].population,
            region: response.data[0].region,
            subRegion: response.data[0].subregion,
            capital: response.data[0].capital[0],
            borderCountries: response.data[0].borders,
            topLevelDomain: response.data[0].tld[0],
            currencies: response.data[0].currencies,
            languages: response.data[0].languages,
        })
```

There's **no need to store an array** in there.

Comment: but when I use a ternary operator I still get the same message? {data ? <div>{data[0].nativeName.common}</div> : null}

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: ternary operator is evalutated as true as data is Array of length 1

Comment: @Fernando see another update to the answer

Answer (score 2):

You have a data mapping error. You are setting your Data incorrectly when trying to set the native name in your data array.

you have:

```
setData([
{
    ...
    nativeName: response.data[0].name.nativeName.nld,
    ...
  }
]);
```

and return

```
                            <div>
                            <span className='title'>Native Name:</span> {data.nativeName.common}
                            </div>
```

But the data structure returned by the api looks different, eg:

```
data: Array(12)
  0: Object
    name: Object
      common: "Eswatini"
      official: "Kingdom of Eswatini"
      nativeName: Object
        eng: Object
        ssw: Object
```

Change it to this instead:

```
setData([
{
    ...
    nativeName: response.data[0].name.common,
    ...
  }
]);
```

and

```
              <div>
                <span>Native Name:</span> {data[0].nativeName}
              </div>
```

Comment: Then, go one step further and set your data as an object. Not an object inside an array. So you can return your data like so: <span>Native Name:</span> {data.nativeName}